# Eloquent query builder get only items which have child items

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So I am trying to get a list of all active clients that have active jobs but I'm at a loss of how to accomplish this. So here is what I have...

```
$query = Client::select( 'clients.*' )->where( 'is_enabled', 1 )->activeJobs();
```

Which throws an error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::activeJobs()
> in my client model i have the activeJobs() function as follows:

```
    public function activeJobs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany( Job::class )->where( 'is_active', 1 );
    }
```

Just to explain what I am after with my query in words, I'm trying to get a collection of all active client items (determined by is_enabled = 1) which have 1 or more active jobs (determined by is_active = 1)

thanks

Comment: Check My Updated anwer, i updated it to clearify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [has/whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

So, what you should do is

```
    $query = Client::select('clients.*')
                   ->whereHas('jobs', fn($query) => $query->where('is_active', 1))
                   ->where('is_enabled', 1)
                   ->get();
```

This will return you a collection of Clients whose Job's is_active column is 1

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I'm looking for :) like the use of the new function format too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$query = Client::select('clients.*')
    ->where('is_enabled', 1)
    ->whereHas('activeJobs', function ($query) {
        $query->where('is_active', 1);
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = Client::has('activeJobs', '>', 1)->get();
```

Comment: this works too but it runs `count` rather than `exists` query which is inefficient in this case

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
$query = Client::with('activeJobs')->select( 'clients.*' )->where( 'is_enabled', 1 );
```

This will return the clients with their relationship(Active Jobs), what you are doing in the code is trying to grab relationship data from collection..

You can either grab the clients, then foreach $client->activeJobs;

or use with which wil return it in query level.

Answer (score -2):

Get active jobs and then collect related users:

```php
$cliensWithActiveJobs = Job::with('client')
    ->where('is_active', 1)
    ->get(['id', 'client_id'])
    ->map(fn ($job) => $job->client)
    ->unique('id');
```

Comment: This is very bad practice. You should filter the return data in the query than in the PHP. If you get big data then this will take huge resources.

Comment: It's not, but correct sollution was proposed by @anuj-shrestha